# Orbeon Forms - Is it it possible to localise shared forms?

Tags: orbeon, xforms

Perhaps a silly question, but is it possible for customers to be able to share a form but it be localised to them?

What I mean by that is, for a given form would it be possible to dynamically change bits of text, for example, changing said text to display the customer's name or other information. Alternatively, would I be expected to create a new form for each customer that I had localised to them?

My motivation for wanting to know this is that I'm currently looking into adopting orbeon forms for a project at work and customers often want identical forms with minor text changes.

Comment: Hi `alms1407`, just checking: does using the duplicate functionality, as suggested in my answer below, work for you, or would you prefer something different? ‑Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel that you are using the term "localize" in a non-traditional way. Typically, localizing refers to *translating* the form. So you might have a version of your form in English, and localized version in Spanish. In your case, it seems that you want to provide *form templates* that your customers can then customize, this instead of the customers having to build their forms from scratch.

You can do this by:

1. Creating your form templates from Form Builder, as you would create "normal" forms.
2. Ship to your customers an installation of Orbeon Forms that includes those templates in its database. (Or provide access to a server that has those templates installed.)
3. Instruct your customers to open the Form Builder summary page, select the template they are interested in, duplicate it, and do their changes on the duplicated form.